MySQL optimize a SQL for a table without indexes
The metadata table of Spring Batch will not be automatically cleaned,
so I tried to clean it manually (provided that other batches processes are executed normally during the cleaning process).
When I tried to clean up the BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS table, I found that the table was locked.
The table structure is:
CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS  (
    JOB_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL ,
    PARAMETER_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
    PARAMETER_TYPE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
    PARAMETER_VALUE VARCHAR(2500) ,
    IDENTIFYING CHAR(1) NOT NULL ,
    constraint JOB_EXEC_PARAMS_FK foreign key (JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
    references BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

The SQL statement is:
SELECT MAX(JOB_EXECUTION_ID) 
    FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION 
    WHERE CREATE_TIME < <ANYTIME>;

DELETE FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS 
    WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID <= <MAX_JOB_EXECUTION_ID>;

The Explain is:



id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
DELETE
BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS
NULL
ALL
JOB_EXEC_PARAMS_FK
NULL
NULL
NULL
10062
100
Using where



How can I optimize SQL to solve the problem of table locking?
I don't know of a way to prevent a table lock from happening if the table without indexes.
Best Regards...

Is there something preventing you from using indices?

@TimBiegeleisen When the amount of data is too large, there may be performance degradation. This is one of the metrics to consider. However, if the problem of locking the table cannot be solved without adding an index, it will be re-evaluated.

Assuming the only SQL executing on this table be the above 2 statements, then the only possible downside to indexing would be the delete; the select should get way faster.

@TimBiegeleisen I do not understand. Is the optimization direction to select first and then delete under the premise of appending index?

If you have an index on that table and records are deleted (or inserted, or updated), then the index may need to be rebuilt.

Hi,@TimBiegeleisen I added an IDX index listed as JOB_EXECUTION_ID to the table, and put in 20,000 records for deletion testing. I found that when the number of deleted records is greater than 5870, a full table scan is performed, and if it is less than 5870, a "range" scan is performed(Index is used). The SQL statement is the same as above. How can I improve my indexes or SQL to ensure that delete operations do not perform a full table scan?

You could try using this statement to do your deletion.
DELETE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARMS
  FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARMS
  JOIN BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION
     ON BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.JOB_EXECUTION_ID = BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARMS.JOB_EXECUTION_ID
 WHERE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.CREATE_TIME < <ANYTIME>
 LIMIT 100;

This will delete up to 1000 rows from the PARMS table that match the expiration criterion you mentioned. Then, you repeat this statement until it deletes no rows.
Why might this work? It limits the number of rows to handle in the delete transaction, which in turn may limit how long the table is locked.
According to the Spring Batch doc I found the BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.CREATE_TIME and BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARMS.JOB_EXECUTION_ID columns already have indexes. That's good because those are the indexes that help your operation. But that doesn't agree with the table definition you showed us.
If your <ANYTIME> is long enough ago that nothing more is happening with the relevant  rows of the database, you could try using  a so-called dirty read to do the deletion. Precede your statements with
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

to get this (somewhat risky) optimization; it saves database overhead by ignoring transactions from other users of the database. (You can't do this with other peoples' money and other transaction-sensitive data.)

Thanks you! This is a new direction that I will try. In addition, for the table definition of Spring Batch, I refer to this link.
